# How to combine the usage of operator all and icontains for mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

For mongoengine, there are operators `all` and `icontains`.  But how can I combine the usage of them?

Say for each item, I just want to match with `icontains` but not `exact`?  I tried to use regex.  I works but unfortunately it would break if I have more than 1 `Q` in the queryset of mongoengine.  Because it would try to `deepcopy` the `pattern` object but unfortunately `pattern` object can't been copied deeply.

Answer (score 1):

actually, I recommend using [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/), install by `easy_install pymongo`, in pymongo, you could try:

```
db.collections.find({'$and':[
    {'field A':re.compile('your pattern')},
    {'$ne':{'field A':'not exact word'}}
]})
```

here, `$ne` and `$and` are native mongo db operators, you could find more details [mongodb advnace query](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries)