# Mongoengine - using icontains with all

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287001/how-to-combine-the-usage-of-operator-all-and-icontains-for-mongoengine) but it does not answer my question, or even pose it very well.

I think that this is best explained with an example:

```
class Blah(Document):
    someList = ListField(StringField())

Blah.drop_collection()

Blah(someList=['lop', 'glob', 'hat']).save()
Blah(someList=['hello', 'kitty']).save()

# One of these should match the first entry
print(Blah.objects(someList__icontains__all=['Lo']).count())
print(Blah.objects(someList__all__icontains=['Lo']).count())
```

I assumed that this would print either `1, 0` or `0, 1` (or miraculously `1, 1`) but instead it gives

```
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metst.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(Blah.objects(someList__all__icontains=['lO']).count())
  File "/home/blah/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.1.4/lib/python3.1/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 1034, in count
    return self._cursor.count(with_limit_and_skip=True)
  File "/home/blah/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.1.4/lib/python3.1/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 608, in _cursor
    self._cursor_obj = self._collection.find(self._query,
  File "/home/blah/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.1.4/lib/python3.1/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 390, in _query
    self._mongo_query = self._query_obj.to_query(self._document)
  File "/home/blah/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.1.4/lib/python3.1/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 213, in to_query
    query = query.accept(QueryCompilerVisitor(document))
  File "/home/blah/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.1.4/lib/python3.1/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 278, in accept
    return visitor.visit_query(self)
  File "/home/blah/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.1.4/lib/python3.1/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 170, in visit_query
    return QuerySet._transform_query(self.document, **query.query)
  File "/home/blah/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.1.4/lib/python3.1/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 755, in _transform_query
    value = field.prepare_query_value(op, value)
  File "/home/blah/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.1.4/lib/python3.1/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 594, in prepare_query_value
    return self.field.prepare_query_value(op, value)
  File "/home/blah/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.1.4/lib/python3.1/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 95, in prepare_query_value
    value = re.escape(value)
  File "/home/blah/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.1.4/lib/python3.1/re.py", line 246, in escape
    return bytes(s)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Neither query works!

Does MongoEngine support some way to search using `icontains` and `all`?  Or some way to get around this?

Note: I want to use MongoEngine, not PyMongo.

Edit: The same issue exists with Python 2.7.3.

Comment: What if you make a raw query, like `Blah.objects(__raw__={"someList": {"$all": ["/10/i"]}}).count()`?

Comment: Using that returns `0` for the count, just like the first print option I described.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've used `0` instead of `O`, try this: `Blah.objects(__raw__={"someList": {"$all": ["/1O/i"]}}).count()`.

Comment: :) Don't worry, I had made the correction.  It does not work.  I will change the original post to `Lo` to remove confusion.

Perhaps this is a mongoDB problem and not a mongoengine problem.  I do not have time to check this right now, but maybe later.

Comment: What did you ultimately do for this? Have same question here

Comment: Sadly I have removed the feature from the product until I have time to go back and figure out a way around this.

Comment: hey, I figured out a way, check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this, as of now(version 0.8.0) is by using a `__raw__` query, possibly combined with `re.compile()`. Like so:

```
import re

input_list = ['Lo']
converted_list = [re.compile(q, re.I) for q in input_list]

print(Blah.objects(__raw__={"someList": {"$all": converted_list}}).count())
```

---

There is currently no way in mongoengine to combine `all` and `icontains`, and the only operator that can be used with other operators is `not`. This is *subtly* mentioned in [the docs](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#query-operators), as in it says that:

> not – negate a standard check, **may be used before other operators** (e.g. Q(age_*not*_mod=5))

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

But it does not say that you can not do this with other operators, which is actually the case.

---

You can confirm this behavior by looking at the source:

version 0.8.0+ ([in module - mongoengine/queryset/transform.py](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/queryset/transform.py#L42) - lines 42-48):

```
if parts[-1] in MATCH_OPERATORS:
    op = parts.pop()

negate = False
if parts[-1] == 'not':
    parts.pop()
    negate = True
```

In older versions the above lines can be seen in *mongoengine/queryset.py* within the `_transform_query` method.